# Why does $\sum_{n\neq0}\:\left|\frac{a_n}{n}\right| \leq \sqrt{\sum_{n\neq0}\frac{1}{n^2}}\sqrt{\sum_{n\neq0}|a_n|^2}$?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

My question is: Why does

$$\sum_{n\neq0}\:\left|\frac{a_n}{n}\right| \leq \sqrt{\sum_{n\neq0}\frac{1}{n^2}}\sqrt{\sum_{n\neq0}|a_n|^2},$$

where $a_n$ is some complex number, $n$ an integer going from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, excluding $n=0$.

From my source:

[image]

Thank you for any help! =)

So lets say I have $a = (a_1, ..., a_k)$ and $b = (b_1, ..., b_k)$

Now I know that:

$$|a\cdot b| \leq||a||\:||b|| $$
$$\left| \sum_{i=1}^k a_ib_i\right| \leq \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^k |a_i|^2}\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^k |b_i|^2}$$

My book says that:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^k |a_ib_i| \leq \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^k |a_i|^2}\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^k |b_i|^2}$$

I also know that by triangle inequality
$$\left| \sum_{i=1}^k a_ib_i\right| \leq \sum_{i=1}^k |a_ib_i|$$

So this is what I see that is claimed by my book:

$$\left| \sum_{i=1}^k a_ib_i\right| \leq \sum_{i=1}^k |a_ib_i| \leq \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^k |a_i|^2}\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^k |b_i|^2}$$

Do you see where I get confused?...

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that when we limit the sum to a finite sum, what you ask to show is just the good old Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:
$$(x_1y_1 + x_2y_2 + \cdots + x_ky_k)^2 \leq (x_1^2 + \cdots + x_k^2)(y_1^2 +\cdots +y_k^2)$$
(Set $x_i$'s as $|a_i|$'s and $y_i$'s as $|1/n|$ terms noting that absolute value signs disappear when squared)

So, any finite sum of the left-hand side is (uniformly) bounded by the right-hand side, and thus the inequality thus follows.

Comment: (Schwarz, no t.)

Comment: +1 Thank for your help =) I still have one problem that confuses me. In your inequality if you take the square root of both sides you get the absolute value of a sum on the left hand side right? But in my inequality I have a sum of absolute values on the left hand side. Doesn't $|a_1| + \cdots + |a_k| \geq |a_1 + \cdots + a_k|$? This confuses me: $|\sum a_n|$ and $\sum |a_n|$, it seems to me they are mixed...

Comment: @Andres: Yup, no t. @ jjepsuomi: I made a minor fix in the solution.

Comment: aah..of course...thank you, see it now x)

Comment: @chriseur sorry to bother you again...I didn't get it after all...x( I even asked my friend and he wondered it too...I'll update my post in a sec, can you comment on it? =)

Comment: Got it, now I see it really x)